# java programming regarding inheritance

Tags: java

```
class student {
    int id = 100;
    String name = "home";
}

class Teststudent1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        student s1 = new student();
        System.out.println(s1.id);
        System.out.println(s1.name);
    }
}
```

In this code, the `Teststudent1` Class is using variable of Class `student` and gives output `100` and `home`.

How it can be possible without inheritance?

Comment: There's no use of inheritance here.

Comment: this is because you assigned the vaue id = 100, home sort of defaults..

Comment: Learn the basics before you start asking questions, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Answer (score 2):

No inheritance involved. You are using an instance of student (s1) directly. (Note: by convention, class names should begin with an upper-case letter)

Answer (score 2):

Inheritance has nothing to do with this. You simply access fields of the `student` class. You can access them because they are "package-private" so can be accessed from classes in the same package.

Comment: I think that you would mean "package-private" .

Comment: @davidxxx Right, package-private is the correct term.

Answer (score 0):

When you don't provide an access modifier(public, protected, private) - **default package level** is imposed on the members/class.

Let's review the access modifier to understand it better -

**Private** - Can accessed only inside the class

**Default package level** - Can access only inside the same package. Means any class, object or method in the same package can access it

**Protected** - Can access inside the same package + subclasses in different package

**Public** - Can access in anywhere.

Now, as you haven't applied any access modifier, by default, it is default package level access and any class, object can access it.
Hence, you can access the members of student class.

Now, try a little experiment, change the access modifier of ID and NAME and run the code like

**NOTE** : Without extend keyword, you can't have inheritance